# Do make seq-locks sense in userspace?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, multiprocessing

AFAIK writers of a seqlock may be scheduled away while having made the seq-counter odd, so this may starve the readers. So do seq-locks imply disabling the scheduler on a core for a for while ?

Comment: It is used for the case of non-preemptible writers in kernel, and multiple non-blocking readers in kernel or user space.

Comment: All possible functions for acquire seqlock in "write" mode also acquires a spinlock: `write_seqlock`, `write_seqlock_bh`, `write_seqlock_irq`, `write_seqlock_irqsave`. So yes, acquiring seqlock for write implies disabling preemption. Since user space code cannot disable preemption for a while, seqlocks won't work for it.